# Building enterprise web application from maven build

Tags: eclipse, deployment, maven-2

I have six projects. Three of them are MyProjectBuild, MyProjectEAR, MyProjectWeb. The other projects are used as modules. I need to run this application on the application server from eclipse directly. How do I achieve that?

I tried using `mvn clean -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse` on MyProjectBuild. Using this I am get an option to run on server. However, I get a dependency errors. Can someone please provide step by step procedure for this?